# Indexing Multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I know that multidimensional numpy arrays may be indexed with other arrays, but I did not figure out how the following works:

I would like to have the the items from `raster`, a 3d numpy array, based on `indx`, a 3d index array:

```
raster=np.random.rand(5,10,50)
indx=np.random.randint(0, high=50, size=(5,10,3))
```

What I want is another array with dimensions of `indx` that holds the values of `raster` based on the index of `indx`.

Comment: Can you add the expected output  to your question? and explain that whats your logic for getting that output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we need in order to properly resolve your indices during broadcasting are two arrays `a` and `b` so that `raster[a[i,j,k],b[i,j,k],indx[i,j,k]]` will be `raster[i,j,indx[i,j,k]]` for `i`,`j`,`k` in corresponding ranges for `indx`'s axes.
The easiest solution would be:

```
x,y,z = indx.shape
a,b,_ = np.ogrid[:x,:y,:z]
raster[a,b,indx]
```

Where `np.ogrid[...]` creates three arrays with shapes `(x,1,1)`, `(1,y,1)` and `(1,1,z)`. We don't need the last one so we throw it away. Now when the other two are broadcast with `indx` they behave exactly the way we need.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, for each row of `indx`, you are trying to index into the corresponding row in `raster`, but the column numbers vary depending on the actual values in `indx`. So, with that assumption, you can use a vectorized approach that uses linear indexing, like so -

```
M,N,R = raster.shape
linear_indx = R*np.arange(M*N)[:,None] + indx.reshape(M*N,-1)
out = raster.ravel()[linear_indx].reshape(indx.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to get 3 random values from each of the 3rd dimension arrays.

You can do this via list-comprehension thanks to [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)

Here's an example using less number of values and integers so the output is easier to read:

```
import numpy as np

raster=np.random.randint(0, high=1000, size=(2,3,10))
indices=np.random.randint(0, high=10, size=(2,3,3))
results = np.array([ np.array([ column[col_indices] for (column, col_indices) in zip(row, row_indices) ]) for (row, row_indices) in zip(raster, indices) ])

print("Raster:")
print(raster)
print("Indices:")
print(indices)
print("Results:")
print(results)
```

**Output:**

```
Raster:
[[[864 353  11  69 973 475 962 181 246 385]
  [ 54 735 871 218 143 651 159 259 785 383]
  [532 476 113 888 554 587 786 172 798 232]]

 [[891 263  24 310 652 955 305 470 665 893]
  [260 649 466 712 229 474   1 382 269 502]
  [323 513  16 236 594 347 129  94 256 478]]]
Indices:
[[[0 1 2]
  [7 5 1]
  [7 8 9]]

 [[4 0 2]
  [6 1 4]
  [3 9 2]]]
Results:
[[[864 353  11]
  [259 651 735]
  [172 798 232]]

 [[652 891  24]
  [  1 649 229]
  [236 478  16]]]
```

It iterates simultaneously over the corresponding 3rd dimension arrays in *raster* and *indices* and uses advanced indexing to slice the desired indices from *raster*.

Here's a more verbose version that does the exact same thing:

```
results = []
for i in range(len(raster)):
    row = raster[i]
    row_indices = indices[i]
    row_results = []
    for j in range(len(row)):
        column = row[j]
        column_indices = row_indices[j]
        column_results = column[column_indices]
        row_results.append(column_results)
    results.append(np.array(row_results))
results = np.array(results)
```